# Is there a function/operation to add place of interest?

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am plotting springs within a place "Christchurch", however, the place does not appear when I run it only the spring locations themselves.

```
# packages
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmapshaper)
library(dplyr)
library(units)
library(terra) 
library(rmapshaper)
library(tidyr)
library(tmaptools)

# reading springs
springs <- st_read("Spring_Locations.geojson")

# reading TA's
TA <- st_read("territorial-authority-2021-generalised.gpkg")

# transforming spring projection
springs <- springs %>% st_transform(crs = "EPSG:2193")

# selecting variables and changing names as we go
TA <- TA %>% select(TA_code = TA2021_V1_00, TA_name = TA2021_V1_00_NAME, land_area_sq_km = LAND_AREA_SQ_KM,
                    area_sq_km = AREA_SQ_KM, shape_length = Shape_Length, geometry = geom)

# filtering greater CHCH springs only
springs_chch <- springs %>%
  st_filter(TA %>% filter(TA_name == "Christchurch City"))

# geocoding
springs_chch_loc2 <- geocode_OSM(springs_chch$ROAD_OR_STREET, crs = 4326, as.sf = TRUE)

tm_shape(springs_chch_loc2, bbox = "Christchurch") +
  tm_dots(col = "red",
          title = "Christchurch Spring Locations",
          alpha = 1) +
  tm_scale_bar(position = c("right", "bottom"), 
             breaks = c(0,1,2)) +
  tm_credits("Data: Canterbury Regional Council, 2016", 
           position=c("right", "bottom"), 
           size = 0.5) +
  tm_layout(bg.color = "lightcyan", 
            frame = T, 
            legend.position = c("left","top"),
            title = "Locations of Springs in Christchurch", 
            title.size = 1,
            title.fontface = "bold",
            legend.title.size = 0.8,
            legend.text.size = 0.6)
```

Would this be due to a geocoding issue? I am new to programming so am unsure of this.

[image]

Comment: When you say the place, you mean a shapefile representing the boundaries of Christchurch or you mean a background map such as googlemaps of OSM?

Comment: Hi @scumbagsurfer, Since the date you asked this question, you may have found the solution to your problem. If not, I believe you would increase your probability of being helped if you made available the two files that are needed (i.e. `geojson` and `gpkg` files) to make your problem reproducible. Cheers.